# Is there a way of calculating the schema that would result from applying a Postgres SQL script

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a Postgres sql script with lots of `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admins (
  id         SERIAL NOT NULL,
  token      TEXT   NOT NULL UNIQUE,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE admins ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS new_col BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;

ALTER TABLE admins
RENAME TO super_admins;
```

Is there a way of turning this script into a simpler script that only creates tables? I.e.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS super_admins (
  id         SERIAL  NOT NULL,
  token      TEXT    NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  new_col    BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Preferably something I could run in a terminal, so I could change my CI to automatically derive the 2nd script from the 1st.

Comment: `pg_dump --schema-only` is probably as close as is easy to get.

Comment: @Jasen So i'd have to actually run my first script, create the db, and then dump the schema? E.g. `cat script.sql | psql mydbname` and then `pg_dump mydbname --schema-only`?

Comment: yeah,  itt's not a lot of work for a server to create some empty tables.